# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start' DataCamp exercise

Tags: python, nlp, ipython, attributeerror, nonetype

I'm doing the Datacamp course on NLP in Python. One of the exercises asks the following:
*Use re.search() to search for the first occurrence of the word "coconuts" in scene_one. Store the result in match. Print the start and end indexes of match using its .start() and .end() methods, respectively.*

I'm doing this:

```
match = re.search("coconuts", scene_one)

print(match.start(), match.end())

print(match)
```

It seems to works properly in the iPython shell but when I run the code on my Jupyter notebooks I get this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-dbcdf93b0e90> in <module>
----> 1 print(match.start(), match.end())

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start'
```

What does it mean?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search `re.search()` will "Return `None` if no position in the string matches the pattern".

Comment: is `scene_one` the same in both iPython and Jupyter?

Comment: When using the result of a `re.search` it is not a good idea to assume success.  Test for `None` first.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to check if a match object exists before invoking any method on it:

```
match = re.search("coconuts", scene_one)
if match is not None:
   print(match.start(), match.end())
   print(match)
```